Textbox data to Gridview
I am trying to below code running ok but please refer to the screenshot.
private void CopyTextBoxToDataGridView()
{
        // Split the lines from the textBox1 text
        string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column 1");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column 2");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column 3");
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] splitLine = lines[i].Split(new char[] { '-', ']' });
            string col1 = splitLine.Length > 0 ? splitLine[0] : string.Empty;
            string col2 = splitLine.Length > 1 ? splitLine[1] : string.Empty;
            string col3 = splitLine.Length > 2 ? splitLine[2] : string.Empty;

            // Check if the next line starts with '['
            if (i + 1 < lines.Length && lines[i + 1].StartsWith("["))
            {
                col3 = "1"; // Set "1" in column 3
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(col1.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), col2.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), col3);
        }
}

Output:

If textbox input not applied timing like 2 then by default in column 3 should be 1.

This is your comment: // Check if the next line starts with '['. Since only the 1st line starts with '[', how do you expect col3 to be 1?

if there is no bracket first to last row then  its should be by default applied value 1 in col3 last row

A TextBox has a Lines property, by the way

Why not default col3 to 1 instead of string.Empty? string col3 = splitLine.Length > 2 ? splitLine[2] : "1";

You should really bind your grid to a datatable and push values into the table, not this VB6 flavored "push values into the control)

That's easy. Just trim and check the value.
You could add a short-if statement like (splitLine[2].toString() != "2" ? "1" : "2")
Or check  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(splitLine[2]) ? "1" : "2") is null or empty.
But to be honest... Adding values like this way is very very bad. You know, every person has his own idea about entering values and this will almost always causing problems. I would recommend using a Textbox for every column and after pushing the 'Apply' or 'Insert' button, check every input from the textboxes if they contain the values you would like to accept.
The most errors occurs with user input! What if somebody enters four instead of 4?
As answer on your comment:
Well, first of all it's not recommended to use a multiline textbox for different values. A better way is to use 3 single-line textboxes and there are 2 ways to check the input for each textbox. The easiest way is to check there values after submitting them with a button or check the input directly while typing in the values. The last one will need TextChanged-event. In the first case you can use a regular expression or (if it must be a number)
int number;
int number2;
bool val1 = int.TryParse(txtValue1.Text.Trim(), out number); 
bool val2 = Regex.IsMatch(txtValue2.Text.Trim(), @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
bool val3 = false;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValue3.Text.Trim())
{
    val3 = int.TryParse(txtValue3.Text.Trim(), out number2);
}
if(val1 & val2 & val3)
{
    //Insert the values into the datagridview.
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("A wrong input has been given!");
}

This very basic and not very optimal but it will do the job.

can you pls share the update code ??

When using a DataGridView, people tend to fiddle directly with Rows and Cells to fill the DataGridView. It is way easier (to understand, to use, to test, to maintain, to reuse) to separate the data from how this data is displayed.
MVVM
In modern programming (or in fact, quite some time now) there is a tendency to separate the data handling (= Model) from how the data is presented to the operator (= View).
This makes it possible to reuse the data while displaying it differently.
For instance, if you have some spreadsheet data, you can display it as a table in a DataGridView, but you could also present it as a graph.
Apart from reusing the Model, it is way easier to unit test it. And as long as you don't change the interface, you can change the internals of the models wihout having to change the View. It is also possible to use the View with simpler mock Model data so you can develop the View without actual Model data. For instance, if your DataGridView should display data from a database, you could feed the View with a list containing the data that your Model will fetch from the database, once it has been developed.
To adapt the View to the Model, an adapter class is needed, usually called the ViewModel. Together these three classes are abbreviated to MVVM. If you are not familiar with this, consider to read some background information about it.
MVVM and your Problem
WinForms supports MVVM using property DataSource.
I assume your DataGridView has always three columns. The first column should displaye the first split part, the second column the second split part etc.
class DisplayedLine             // TODO: invent a proper identifiers
{
    public string Split1 {get; set;}  
    public string Split2 {get; set;}
    public string Split3 {get; set;}
}

It is easier if you use visual studio designer to create the DataGridView and add the DataGridViewProperties, but if you can convince your design officer (the person who is responsible for the quality of designs), you can add the columns in your code. My advice would be to do this in the constructor, so you don't have to check if they have been created or not.
In the constructor you can also define which column should display which property.
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponents()

    // if needed: create and add the three DataGridViewColumns
    // define which column will show which property of DisplayedLine
    this.col1.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedLine.Split1);
    this.col2.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedLine.Split2);
    this.col3.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedLine.Split3);
}

You could also do this using Visual Studio Designer, but that will use strings. Doing this yourself in the constructor has the advantage that if in future you decide to change the names of the Properties and forget to change the strings, the compiler will complain.
You need procedures that reads the data from the TextBox and to convert the read data to a sequence of DisplayedLines:
IEnumerable<string> ReadTextBox()
{
    return this.TextBox1.Lines;
}

IEnumerable<DisplayedLine> ToDisplayedLines(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    // TODO: implement. Code is similar to your own code. Not part of the question
}

By separating the TextBox (=view) from the Model, you won't have to change a lot if in future you decide to change the TextBox into a RichTextBox, or if you want to read the data from a TextFile, or read it from a database, or fetch the data from the internet.
Now to display a sequence of DisplayedLines in the DataGridView is a one liner:
BindingList<DisplayedLine> DisplayedLines
{
    get => (BindingList<DisplayedLine>) this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

By putting the data in a BindingList makes it easier to read the changes made by the operator in the DataGridView. If you don't need that, you can use a List or a Collection instead of the BindingList
Usage
Let's assume that the operator edits the TextBox and clicks on the Apply Now button to indicate he has finished editing, and that the text should be displayed in the DataGridView:
void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ShowTextBoxInDataGridView();
}

void ShowTextBoxInDataGridView()
{
    // Read the TextBox, convert to a sequence of DisplayedLines and display it
    IEnumerable<string> textBoxLines = this.ReadTextBox();
    IEnumerable<DisplayedLine> linesToDisplay = this.ToDisplayedLines(textBoxLines);
    this.DisplayedLines = new BindingList<DisplayedLine>(linesToDisplay.ToList());

    // or if you want it in one statement, not sure though if this improves readability
    this.DisplayedLines = new BindingList<DisplayedLine>(this.ToDisplayedLines(this.ReadTextBox()).ToList());
}

Again, I've separated the clicking on the button (= View) from the handling of the data (= Model), so you can reuse the code if you want to do the same when selecting a menu item.
Because I used a BindingList, the operator can change the contents of the DataGridView. He can add and remove rows, and he can change values of the displayed properties.
So if the operator presses OK button to indicate he has finished editing, you can easily process the changed data:
void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ProcessChangedDataGridView();
}

void ProcessChangedDataGridView()
{
    ICollection<DisplayedLine> editedLines = this.DisplayedLines;

    // compare with (copy of) original data to detect which DisplayedLines are
    // added / removed / rearaanged / changed and process them:
    // Of of scope of this question 
}

Two useful properties
Now that you've separated the Model from the View it is easy to access the current DisplayedLine and the DisplayedLines that the operator selects:
DisplayedLine CurrentDisplayedLine => (DisplayedLine)
    this.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<DisplayedLine> SelectedDisplayedLines => 
    this.DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
        .Cast<DisplayedLine>();

Summary
Separating the Model from the View, makes it easier to understand the code. It is easier to unit test the Model without the view.
The Model can be reused with a different View and the View can be reused with a different Model, for instance with Mock data for a unit text.
Although the separation tends to lead to a lot of methods and properties, most properties are very small, usually one or two lines.
Because everything is strictly typed, the compiler will complain if you try use incorrect types.
If you change your model, for instance fetch the data from a database instead of from a TextBox, changes will be small. The View doesn't have to change. the ViewModel will adapt the changed Model to the View. Similarly if you change the View, for instance you want to show four columns, the Model doesn't have to change, the ViewModel will take care that the Model fits to the View.
